# What is the scope of a ruby string?

Tags: ruby, string

This is what I tried:

```
a = "Hello world"
a.object_id    # => -633222538
b = a
b.object_id    # => -633222538
b << " i say"  # => "Hello world i say"
a              # => "Hello world i say"
```

Why is it that both the variables `b` and `a` have the same object id? Also, when I change `b`, how did `a` also change?

**Update:**
How about when the variable is passed as an argument to a method? Why is the receiving variable having the same reference?

Comment: Because you set b to point at the same string as a?

Comment: that is exactly my question.. why does it copy the reference instead of the value?

Comment: Why would it copy the object unless you tell it to? Consider a giant list: would you expect a copy, and/or a deep copy, to be created upon copying the reference?

Comment: then how is assigning integer value different from string values? because this is not the case with integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are referencing the same object:

```
a = "Hello world"     # a now references #-633222538
b = a                 # b now references #-633222538, too
b << " i say"         # this appends " i say" to #-633222538
a                     # a still references #-633222538
```

[`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) doesn't assign a new object, it appends to the given string, thus *changing* the receiver.

I you want a copy, you can use [`clone`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) or [`dup`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup):

```
b = a.clone
a == b      #=> true (same string values)
a.equal? b  #=> false (different objects)
```

#### Regarding integers

There's no difference in referencing:

```
a = 100
a.object_id  #=> 201
b = a
b.object_id  #=> 201
```

Now both, `a` and `b` reference the same object. The only difference is that an integer cannot be changed in Ruby, they are fixed.

#### Passing variables as arguments

Again, the reference is passed:

```
a = "foo"
p = proc { |x| x << "bar" }
p.call(a)
a
#=> "foobar"
```

Answer (score 2):

**ENTER REFERENCES**

The answer is that variables in Ruby (with a few exceptions, most notably variables bound to integers) don’t hold object values. `a` doesn’t contain "Hello world". Rather, `a` contains a reference to a string object. It’s the string object that has the characteristic of containing the letters that make up "Hello World".

In an assignment with a variable name on the left and an object on the right, the variable receives a reference to the object. In an assignment from one variable to another (`a = b`), the variable on the left receives a copy of the reference stored in the variable on the right, with the result that both variables now contain references to the same object.

The fact that variables hold references to objects has implications for operations that change objects. The string-concat operation

```
b << " i say"
```

concats the characters of the string to which `b` is a reference with the text " i say". The variable `a` contains another reference to the same string object. Even though the replace message goes to `b`, it causes a change to the object to which the reference in `b` refers. When you print out `a`, you see the result: the contents of the string have changed.

**Some objects in Ruby are stored in variables as immediate values**. These include in- tegers, symbols (which look like `:this`), and the special objects `true`, `false`, and `nil`. When you assign one of these values to a variable (`x = 1`), the variable holds the value itself, rather than a reference to it.

Copied and modified from [Manning The Well Grounded Rubyist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657).

Comment: is there anywhere to lookup a list of how various types of objects behave upon assignment?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe someone else can help with that.

Comment: Integers, `true`, `false` and `nil` are all objects: `1.is_a? Object #=> true`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you called a mutable function on a variable which shared the same object with another variable. if you instead did b = b + 'i say' a would be left unchanged.

Comment: are all ruby variables mutable by default or is it just strings?

Comment: No they are not all mutable, and if you want to turn a mutable object into an immutable object simply call a.freeze where a is your variable.

Comment: if you want to see which objects are immutable or mutable simply chain on the method .frozen?

Comment: sorry i meant to ask, are all objects mutable by default? For example: integer does not behave like strings with respect to references

Comment: They are not all mutable by default, you should power up the irb, and just go c = 10   c.frozen?   and it will be very clear :).

Answer (score 0):

The variables `a` and `b` are references to a String object. When you did the `b = a` assignment, you copied the reference. It doesn't make a new copy of the object. If you want to copy the string object into a new object, you might do something like this:

```
a = "abc"
b = ""  [or, b = String.new]
b << a
```

Now `a` and `b` will be different, independent string objects with the value "abc".